# How can I find my Apple Developer Team id and Team Agent Apple ID?

Tags: ios

I am trying to transfer an app.  I am having troubles finding my team agent apple id and my team id.  I have found it before and I have searched for 30 min without any luck now that i need it.

The person trying to transfer the app to me gets to view in this image and I don't know where to find this info.

[image: The person trying to transfer the app to me gets to this view and I don't know where to find this info.]

Comment: I wonder why does Apple make it so complicated, and don't fix these issues

Answer (score 296, accepted):

You can find your team id here:

https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership

This will get you to your Membership Details, just scroll down to **Team ID**

Comment: Awesome I can get my team ID right there.  Do you know how I can get my Team Agent Apple ID?  Is it known as something else?

Comment: It's moved since. pshah's answer is the most recently valid answer.

Comment: This does not show how to get team agent AppleID, even after the edit

Comment: Turns out if you account is individual, you will not see a team agent AppleID

Comment: @DavidNathan I just checked it seems fine still

Comment: Ok, so it is not working for accounts that did not purchase the apple developer program

Comment: For me, clicking on the link directly redirected to https://developer.apple.com/account/#!/overview/. To get to the "Membership" page, click the "Membership" menu item on the left

Answer (score 81):

If you're on OSX you can also find it your keychain. Your developer and distribution certificates have your Team ID in them.

Applications -> Utilities -> Keychain Access.

Under the 'login' Keychain, go into the 'Certificates' category.

Scroll to find your development or distribution certificate. They will read:

iPhone Distribution: *Team Name* (*certificate id*)

or

iPhone Developer: *Team Name* (*certificate id*)

Simply **double-click** on the item, and the

## "Organizational Unit"

is the "Team ID"

[image]

Note that this is the only way to find your

## "Personal team" ID

You can not find the "Personal team" ID on the Apple web interface.

For example, if you are automating a build from say Unity, during development you'll want it to appear in Xcode as your "Personal team" - this is the only way to get that value.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, it's good to know for the sake of completeness. However, that assumes that you have already setup your developer certificate on that computer. This method would not work on any non-dev machine.

Comment: Wait, is this correct? I think it's not - I think the stuff in brackets is the certificate ID. To see the Team ID assigned to this certificate, you can "Right Click > Get Info" and see under "Organizational Unit". This is also a way to distinguish between a personal team and a organizational team certificate - for the organizational team, the Organizational Unit matches the Team ID.

Comment: @NikolaySuvandzhiev - you are CORRECT, it seemed to be a typo in this great answer.  I edited it to fix it.  It is now CORRECT!  A great answer.

Comment: This didnt work for me in:  https://github.com/appium/ios-uicatalog/tree/master/UIKitCatalog

Answer (score 23):

For personal teams

```
grep DEVELOPMENT_TEAM MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

should give you the team ID

```
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = ZU88ND8437;
```

Comment: Out of all the answers here, this was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

You can find the Team ID via this link: https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary

Comment: This now redirects back to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome. The ID seems to have moved again

Answer (score 17):

Apple has changed the interface.

The team ID could be found via this link:
https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership

Answer (score 6):

There are ways you can check even if you are not a paid user.
You can confirm TeamID from Xcode.
[Build setting] Displayed on tooltip of development team.

Comment: This is the only way that seems to work for a personal (free) account, as of today. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**2023**

You can get it on the page [Apple Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account/) and select from the menu above **Membership Details** (see 1st screenshot)

[image]

Your **team ID** will be here (see 2nd screenshot)

[image]

If you prefer the command line, you can use the command in the terminal *in your project directory*:

```
grep DEVELOPMENT_TEAM *.xcodeproj/*.pbxproj -m 1 | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//'
```

You will get something like this line:

```
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 473A04LG6W;
```

Other options you can get on the official page [Developer Account Help](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/) (they made it very convenient).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to get this from the command line (Terminal) so I came up with this bash script

Link to [gist](https://gist.github.com/luckman212/ec52e9291f27bc39c2eecee07e7a9aa7)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#requires openssl@3 from Homebrew
_openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl 2>/dev/null)/bin/openssl
[[ -x $_openssl ]] || { echo "missing openssl, try \`brew install openssl\`"; exit 1; }

#find development cert
id=$(security find-identity -v -p codesigning | head -1)
[[ -n $id ]] || exit 1
cn=$(sed -En 's/^.*Apple Development.*\((.*)\).*$/\1/p' <<<"$id")
sha1=$(sed -En 's/^.*([A-F0-9]{40}).*$/\1/p' <<<"$id")
[[ -n $cn && -n $sha1 ]] || { echo "could not find valid development cert"; exit 1; }

#make temp dir
outdir=$(mktemp -d /private/tmp/teamid.XXXXXX)
[[ -n $outdir ]] || { echo "error creating temp dir"; exit 1; }

#export cert
if ! security find-certificate -c "$cn" -Z -p >"${outdir}/${cn}.pem"; then
  echo "error exporting cert from Keychain"
  exit 1
fi

#check for hash match
certhash=$(awk -F: '/SHA-1 hash:/{sub(" ","",$2); print $2}' "${outdir}/${cn}.pem")
[[ "$certhash" == "$sha1" ]] || { echo "hash mismatch!"; exit 1; }

#output DEVELOPMENT_TEAM
$_openssl x509 -in "${outdir}/${cn}.pem" -subject -noout |
sed -En 's/.*OU = ([^,]+),.*$/\1/p'

#cleanup
rm -r "${outdir:?}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's now under [Certificates, Identities & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list) top right you have your name in the first line, and in the second your name again and right to it is the Team ID.

Answer (score 0):

###### For a flutter project and personal team.

navigate to below address and search for `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM`
you should find some thing like this `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 64F9WR9M48`

`ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to find TeamID from Terminal

**grep DEVELOPMENT_TEAM /Users/..../XXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj**